# How can noisy components be identified using the ICA method with file.edf in python?

Tags: python, artifacts

I am trying to remove muscle artifacts from an EEG signal corresponding to an epileptic patient. For that, I used the fastICA method with python. The figure below represents the independent components:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGFeF.png)

Unfortunately, I could not distinguish the components corresponding to the artifacts. Is there a way to help me know which components to remove?

Answer (score 0):

first of thing you should know how an eeg signal look like. I think in the picture attached ICA21, ICA7 and ICA2 is completely noisy data

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible given the data that you have, but one possibility is to frame it as a supervised problem. Say you have a few epileptic patients' EEGs and a few from non-epileptic patients. You can apply an `ICA` decomposition to the whole dataset, and then use each component by itself as a feature vector (maybe discretizing it) to predict the class (i.e., epileptic vs. non-epileptic).

The noise components should have no predictive value, so you might be able to find that a cluster of components has a (statistically) significantly higher predictive value than another. This will require manually looking at the accuracy value of each component and making a subjective decision, but maybe it can help as an exploratory analysis.

Of course, this only works if you have data from multiple patients.